# Inject custom Javascript before every page load on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, firefox, mobile-safari, javascript-injection, mobile-chrome

I am using [weinre](https://github.com/apache/cordova-weinre) for remotely debugging an android chrome browser. I have to include a custom javascript file in each page for establishing communication between weinre server and the mobile browser.

How can I inject custom JS on each page on a mobile browser ?

To start with chrome on android will be a good option,  hints for other browsers (Safari on IOS and Firefox on Android) will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Something like User Script for Opera Mobile browser. http://www.opera.com/docs/userjs/

That will be included on every page.

Comment: If you do not use a mobile browser with extensions, your only option is to set up a local proxy server and connect the phone on it. Then code the proxy to insert the script after each <head>.